# pdb for .pyc file: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, pdb

I am trying to convert flag.pyc to flag.py by uncompyle6. However, it fails. Therefore, I have decided to use pdb debugger to run the flag.pyc. Here is the command:
`python -mpdb /Users/frank/Desktop/pep8/flag.pyc`

However, The command line gives me an error`ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`

I know the command `sed -i "" 's/\x0//g' /Users/frank/Desktop/pep8/flag.pyc`. But it returns `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

I also know the command `tr -d '\000' </Users/frank/Desktop/pep8/flag.pyc >/Users/frank/Desktop/pep8/flag2.pyc`. But it returns `tr: Illegal byte sequence`

My environment is MacOS with python3.8.0. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think pyc file could be used with pdb, it doesn't contain source code.

Comment: @georgexsh BTW the trepan debuggers however _can_ debug pyc or bytecode files.

Comment: @rocky wow trepan is very cool

Comment: @georgexsh Thanks for the kind word.  trepan has been around for a decade in some form or other. In fact is is in need of rewrite. But the fact that so few people know or care about it, has largely let me just keep it to the level of where it does the stuff I want and work around the warts. Equally cool I think is https://pypi.org/project/x-python/